# Validation accuracy not improving after reaching 90%

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

I have around 14,000 images for face detection binary classification task. Around 12,000 images are used for training and 2,200 for validation. My CNN architecture is as follows -

```
regularizer = tf.keras.regularizers.l2(l=0.001)
init = tf.initializers.he_uniform()
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), strides = (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=regularizer, input_shape=(ht, wd, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (5, 5), (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), (1, 1), padding='same', activation='relu', kernel_initializer=init, kernel_regularizer=regularizer),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), (2, 2)),

    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),

    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation = 'relu', kernel_regularizer= regularizer),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid')
])
```

My input image dimensions are 150*180*3. The CNN has about 900k - 1M  parameters. I'm using batch size of 16/32. 
Also, my learning rate(initial lr=0.001) scheduler of Adam optimizer is like this

```
reduce_lr_2 = tf.keras.callbacks.ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', 
                                             factor=0.2, 
                                             patience=2, 
                                             verbose=0, 
                                             mode='auto',
                                             min_delta=0.0001, 
                                             cooldown=1,
                                             min_lr=0)
```

I applied data augmentation of many types. Training accuracy I reach is about 95-96% and validation accuracy I achieve is about 90%. I've tried changing a lot of hyper parameters but the validation accuracy remains stuck at around 90%. Is there any way to improve the validation accuracy?

Comment: What does your loss plot look like? Do validation dataset and train dataset come form the same distribution? what size they are? is the model overfitting?

Comment: Yes, they are from same distribution. The sizes have already been mentioned. I don't think the model is overfitting. And val loss seems to be constant after reaching 90% Val acc and after some epochs, val loss increases slightly and fluctuates.

Comment: Do you have a loss plot

Comment: val loss seems to be constant after reaching 90% Val acc and after some epochs, val loss increases slightly and fluctuates.

Comment: Also to add to that, val loss and training loss almost remains same until both the accuracy reaches 87-88%. After that training loss decreases a lot and val loss gets to a value such that val acc is 90%.

Comment: Once your validation loss starts increasing and diverging from training loss, you've begun overfitting.

Comment: @Andy so what should I do now to remove overfitting since I have used all regularization techniques. I tried increasing L2' s lambda but there were no differences.

Comment: You can increase your patience parameter.

Comment: @SaankhyaMondal add dropout layers, specifically `SpatialDropout2D` for yours.

Comment: reduce the model size. also, a batchsize of 16/32 is rather small when using batchnorm. you might want to increase this to at least 128 and see how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

There are 4 ways to improve deep learning performance:

1. Improve Performance With Data.
2. Improve Performance With Algorithms.
3. Improve Performance With Algorithm Tuning.
4. Improve Performance With Ensembles.

**Improve Performance With Data:**

Get More Data.
Invent More Data.
Rescale Your Data.
Transform Your Data.
Feature Selection

**Improve Performance With Algorithms**

*Spot-Check Algorithms:* Maybe your chosen algorithms is not the best for your problem.
*Resampling Methods:* You must know how good your models are. Is your estimate of the performance of your models reliable?

**Improve Performance With Algorithm Tuning**

some ideas on tuning your neural network algorithms in order to get more out of them.

Diagnostics.
Weight Initialization.
Learning Rate.
Activation Functions.
Network Topology.
Batches and Epochs.
Regularization.
Optimization and Loss.
Early Stopping.

**Improve Performance With Ensembles**

three general areas of ensembles you may want to consider:

Combine Models.
Combine Views.
Stacking.

check below link for further information: https://machinelearningmastery.com/improve-deep-learning-performance/